# How to optimize for both scenarios when a join is faster than dense_rank only when the result set is small?

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

When unfiltered, `dense_rank` on FeedDeliveryNutrients.NutrientID over 150,000 rows is 3.5x faster than joining to Nutrients with `row_number` on Nutrients.ID and using the joined row number. When filtered to a specific flock, joining with `row_number` is 9x faster.

Is there any optimization technique that could get the best of both worlds **in a single query**?

Fastest when unfiltered (150,000 rows returned):

```
select
    FeedDeliveries.FlockID,
    FeedDeliveryID,
    DeliveryLb,
    Bin,
    DeliveryDate,
    FormulaID,
    FeedEnergy,
    Nutrient1, Nutrient2, Nutrient3, Nutrient4, Nutrient5, Nutrient6, Nutrient7, Nutrient8, Nutrient9, Nutrient10, Nutrient11, Nutrient12, Nutrient13, Nutrient14, Nutrient15
from (
    select
        FeedDeliveryID,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 1 then Amount end) as Nutrient1,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 2 then Amount end) as Nutrient2,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 3 then Amount end) as Nutrient3,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 4 then Amount end) as Nutrient4,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 5 then Amount end) as Nutrient5,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 6 then Amount end) as Nutrient6,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 7 then Amount end) as Nutrient7,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 8 then Amount end) as Nutrient8,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 9 then Amount end) as Nutrient9,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 10 then Amount end) as Nutrient10,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 11 then Amount end) as Nutrient11,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 12 then Amount end) as Nutrient12,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 13 then Amount end) as Nutrient13,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 14 then Amount end) as Nutrient14,
        sum(case when dense_rank = 15 then Amount end) as Nutrient15
    from (select *, dense_rank() over (partition by FeedDeliveryID order by NutrientID) as dense_rank from dbo.FeedDeliveryNutrients) n
    group by FeedDeliveryID
) pvt
join dbo.FeedDeliveries on FeedDeliveries.ID = FeedDeliveryID
```

Fastest when filtered by dbo.FeedDeliveries.FlockID (~100 rows returned):

```
select
    FeedDeliveries.FlockID,
    FeedDeliveryID,
    DeliveryLb,
    Bin,
    DeliveryDate,
    FormulaID,
    FeedEnergy,
    Nutrient1, Nutrient2, Nutrient3, Nutrient4, Nutrient5, Nutrient6, Nutrient7, Nutrient8, Nutrient9, Nutrient10, Nutrient11, Nutrient12, Nutrient13, Nutrient14, Nutrient15
from (
    select
        FeedDeliveryID,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 1 then Amount end) as Nutrient1,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 2 then Amount end) as Nutrient2,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 3 then Amount end) as Nutrient3,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 4 then Amount end) as Nutrient4,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 5 then Amount end) as Nutrient5,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 6 then Amount end) as Nutrient6,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 7 then Amount end) as Nutrient7,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 8 then Amount end) as Nutrient8,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 9 then Amount end) as Nutrient9,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 10 then Amount end) as Nutrient10,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 11 then Amount end) as Nutrient11,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 12 then Amount end) as Nutrient12,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 13 then Amount end) as Nutrient13,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 14 then Amount end) as Nutrient14,
        sum(case when n.row_number = 15 then Amount end) as Nutrient15
    from dbo.FeedDeliveryNutrients
    join (select *, row_number() over (order by ID) as row_number from dbo.Nutrients) n on n.ID = NutrientID
    group by FeedDeliveryID
) pvt
join dbo.FeedDeliveries on FeedDeliveries.ID = FeedDeliveryID
```

Comment: So each FeedDeliveryID will have exactly 15 Nutrients?  And could you list which table the columns are in?

Comment: No. There is an variable user-configured number of nutrients. This is basically a pivot. The table which columns are in?

Comment: Not clear to me how the second filters on FlockID but pivot is not something I strong on.  But if you want an answer then I think you need better problem statement than best of these two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got the answer. Optimize for the most critical scenario.

From start I can use optimize for the 150.000 rows scenario but you must sniff a bit on your actual production server. If that 150.000 only happens a few times /week and the 100 rows ill hit your server many times/minute that is the more critical for you.

Comment: I still have the question- is there any optimization technique that could get the best of both worlds in a *single* query?

Comment: I don't knows! But long ago I got a similar problem, but for my luck there are a ID passed to filter the rows and sometimes that parameter was passed as null. I did two SPs to cover both cases. Maybe you can create both SPs and use some heuristic to know when to use one or another.